# Remove characters outside of the BMP (emoji's) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 266-266: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk`

I'm parsing the data, and some emoji's falls to array. `data = 'this variable contains some emoji'sツ'` I want: `data = 'this variable contains some emoji's'`

How I can remove these characters from my data or handle this situation in Python 3?

Comment: How about some relevant pieces of code?...and is this related to `Tkinter` ?

Comment: I'm parsing the data, and some emoji's falls to array.
data = 'this variable contains some emoji'sツ'
I want:
data = 'this variable contains some emoji's'

Comment: ツ is not an emoji and inside the BMP. You want to remove that too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the goal is just to remove all characters above `'\uFFFF'`, the straightforward approach is to do just that:

```
data = "this variable contains some emoji'sツ"
data = ''.join(c for c in data if c <= '\uFFFF')
```

It's possible your string is in decomposed form, so you may need [to `normalize` it to composed form](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) first so the non-BMP characters are identifiable:

```
import unicodedata

data = ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', data) if c <= '\uFFFF')
```

Comment: For whatever reason this didn't work for me with Python 2.7.5. (I tried both solutions.) The lowercase characters were stripped out. Instead I used `re_pattern = re.compile(u'[^\u0000-\uFFFF]', re.UNICODE); data = re_pattern.sub('', data)`

Comment: @EricKlien: This answer was for Python 3; if you tried to use it in Python 2 without a `u` prefix, it would make `str`, not `unicode`, and the comparisons wouldn't work. Your inputs would need to be made `unicode`, and the literal being tested against would need the `u` prefix, making it `u'\uFFFF'`. If you do that, [it works just fine](https://tio.run/##PY4xDoJAEEV7TjHRYsHAFlbGSOspbFZYZAjMkN1BQqsews7DeQFvgICJ0838@f@/dpCSaTuOa0g2CWScI1320EmR7OZLgE3LTgA59oMPciMGUuhWUqKHq3FozrWdbCQGyYPnxoJtuELl3/fH5/W8rf4mpXTFSGEGBTvIAAkWCYtpOcwPp@44jYoCZM2tpXDq1F5y7kQXWFviMIpB9SoGSz/WVC2sKtK9Q7HhnBiN4xc).

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> import string
>>> printable = set(string.printable)
>>> filter(lambda x: x in printable, data)
"this variable contains some emoji's"
```

For BMP read this: [removing emojis from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: That would eliminate anything outside the printable ASCII range, not just stuff outside the BMP. Also, on Python 3, `filter` returns a generator always, not a `str`/`tuple`/`list` by argument type. Lastly, don't bother with `filter`/`map` if you need a `lambda` to do it; the genexpr/listcomp will be faster and more succinct. `''.join(x for x in data if x in printable)` (though in this case, `''.join(filter(printable.__contains__, data))` would get the speed the `lambda` version doesn't).

Comment: Yea...I was to comment about it as well...only printable ASCII range

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ooops... I thought that he wants to remove all non-ascii, not only BMP... sorry