# Add spaces in special characters for emojis using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a sentence by combining emoji encoding and I want to separate after "\u" characters

```py
sentance = "Whoaaa\\ud83d\\udc4f"
```

and other case :

```py
sentance = "blabla whoaaa\\ud83d\\udc4f blabla"
```

I want the results like this:

```py
result= "blabla whoaaa \\ud83d\\udc4f blabla"
```

or

```py
sentance = "Whoaaa \\ud83d\\udc4f"
```

Comment: Something simple find `r"\\u(?<!\s\\u)"` replace `r" \\u"`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression might do that:

```
(?:\s|^)([^\\]+)(?=\\u|\\\\u)
```

#### Test with `re.sub`

```
import re

regex = r"(?:\s|^)([^\\]+)(?=\\u|\\\\u)"
test_str = "blabla whoaaa\\\\ud83d\\\\udc4f blabla blabla whoaaa\\\\ud83d\\\\udc4f\\\\ud83d\\\\udc4f blabla\\\\ud83d blabla\\\\ud83d blabla\\\\ud83d "
subst = "\\1 "

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
blabla whoaaa \\ud83d\\udc4f blabla blabla whoaaa \\ud83d\\udc4f\\ud83d\\udc4f blabla \\ud83d blabla \\ud83d blabla \\ud83d
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xtN0iB/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Comment: OK, I have got an answer from you, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be hard to do in a regular expression since the \u is not a character but part of a unicode value syntax...

what I would do is test for each char if its an `emoji` like in the question:
[How to check the Emoji property of a character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925492/how-to-check-the-emoji-property-of-a-character-in-python)

```
result = "".join([" " + c if test_emoji(c) else c for c in test_str])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile('^[A-Za-z\s]*')
sentance1 = "Whoaaa\\ud83d\\udc4f"
sentance2 = "blabla whoaaa\\ud83d\\udc4f blabla"

string_before_emoji = pattern.findall(sentance1)[0]
emoji_only = sentance1.split(string_before_emoji)[1].replace('\\', '\\\\')
print(f"{string_before_emoji} {emoji_only}")
# Whoaaa \\ud83d\\udc4f

string_before_emoji = pattern.findall(sentance2)[0]
emoji_only = sentance2.split(string_before_emoji)[1].replace('\\', '\\\\')
print(f"{string_before_emoji} {emoji_only}")
# blabla whoaaa \\ud83d\\udc4f blabla
```

regex pattern I used,

[image]

Comment: pattern.findall(sentance)[0] in other case not to use

Comment: I just select whole string before emojis  and after that put an extra space and combined all the other emojis into it @AlhamsyaBintangDyasta.

Comment: I just changed my question

Comment: I just change my regex, please check it again. It's now working for your latest changes and visually display the new regex @AlhamsyaBintangDyasta.