# Remove all emojis from a string in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, unicode

I made a Mastodon / Twitter <--> IRC bot a while back. It's been working great, but someone complained that when people use emojis on mastodon (which seems to happen a lot in some usernames ..) it breaks his terminal.

I was wondering if there is a way to remove those from the ByteStrings before sending them to IRC (or at least provide an option to do so), googling a bit I found this : [removing emojis from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python)

Looks like \U0001F600-\U0001F64F should be the emoji range if I understand it correctly, but I've never been big with regex. Any easy-ish way to translate that to Haskell ? I've tried reading up a bit on regex but I only get "lexical error in string/character literal at character 'U'" when I try, I assume that syntax must be a python thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a emoji or unicode expert, but this seems to work:

```
isEmoji :: Char -> Bool
isEmoji c = let uc = fromEnum c
            in uc >= 0x1F600 && uc <= 0x1F64F

str = "wew"
```

As Daniel Wagner points out, this can be made even better:

```
isEmoji :: Char -> Bool
isEmoji c = c >= '\x1F600' && c <= '\x1F64F'
```

Demo in ghci:

```
λ> str
"\128513wew\128513"
λ> filter isEmoji str
"\128513\128513"
λ> filter (not . isEmoji) str
"wew"
```

Explanation: `fromEnum` function converts the character to the corresponding `Int` value defined by the Unicode. I just check for the unicode range of emoji in the function to determine if it's actually an emoji.

Comment: Looks like it works great ! Thanks a lot, it's actually a lot simpler than I expected. A simple >= <= ..

Comment: No need to `fromEnum`, just `isEmoji c = c >= '\x1f600' && c <= '\x1f64f'`.

Comment: The range is 0x1f000..0x1f9ff: http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Answer (score 3):

Unicode characters are represented by a single backslash, followed by an optional `x` for hexadecimal, `o` for octal and none for decimal number representing the character [0]:

```
putStrLn "\x1f600" --
```

Here, `\x` is a prefix for the hexadecimal representation of the first emoji character in Unicode.

You can now remove the emojis using RegExp or you could simply do:

```
emojis = concat [['\x1f600'..'\x1F64F'],
                 ['\x1f300'..'\x1f5ff'],
                 ['\x1f680'..'\x1f6ff'],
                 ['\x1f1e0'..'\x1f1ff']]
someString = "hello "
removeEmojis = filter (`notElem` emojis)

putStrLn . removeEmojis $ someString -- "hello "
```

[0] [Haskell Language 2010: Lexical Structure#Character and String Literals](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#dx7-20001)

Comment: Thanks, that does work ! I went with the other answer 'cause it's lighter I think, but both achieve what I was looking for