# Remove Emoji's from multilingual Unicode text

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to remove *just* Emoji from Unicode text. I tried the various methods [described in another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python) but none of those are removing all emojis / smileys completely. For example:

Solution 1:

```
def remove_emoji(self, string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                           u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                           u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                           u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                           u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', string)
```

Leaves in  in the following example:

```
Input: తెలంగాణ రియల్ ఎస్టేట్ 
Output: తెలంగాణ రియల్ ఎస్టేట్
```

Another attempt, solution 2:

```
def deEmojify(self, inputString):
    returnString = ""
    for character in inputString:
        try:
            character.encode("ascii")
            returnString += character
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            returnString += ''
    return returnString
```

Results in removing any non-English character:

```
 Input: Testరియల్ ఎస్టేట్ A.P&T.S. 
 Output: Test  A.P&T.S.
```

It removes not only all of the emoji but it also removed the non-English characters because of the `character.encode("ascii")`; my non-English inputs can not be encoded into ASCII.

Is there any way to properly remove Emoji from international Unicode text?

Comment: New emoji's are added to the Unicode standard regularly; you'll need to keep updating those regexes.

Comment: The emoji that is left in your first example is U+1F91D, [added in Unicode 9.0](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-9.0/). And [Unicode 10.0](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-10.0/) and [Unicode 11.0](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-11.0/) have expanded the list again. I'm sure version 12.0 will require more updates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The regex is outdated. It appears to cover Emoji's defined up to Unicode 8.0 (since [U+1F91D HANDSHAKE](https://emojipedia.org/handshake/) was added in Unicode 9.0). The other approach is just a very inefficient method of force-encoding to ASCII, which is rarely what you want when just removing Emoji (and can be much more easily and efficiently achieved with `text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`).

If you need a more up-to-date regex, take one from [a package that is actively trying to keep up-to-date on Emoji](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji); it specifically supports generating such a regex:

```
import emoji

def remove_emoji(text):
    return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(u'', text)
```

The package is currently up-to-date for Unicode 11.0 and has the infrastructure in place to update to future releases quickly. All your project has to do is upgrade along when there is a new release.

Demo using your sample inputs:

```
>>> print(remove_emoji(u'తెలంగాణ రియల్ ఎస్టేట్ '))
తెలంగాణ రియల్ ఎస్టేట్ 
>>> print(remove_emoji(u'Testరియల్ ఎస్టేట్ A.P&T.S. '))
Testరియల్ ఎస్టేట్ A.P&T.S.
```

Note that the regex works on *Unicode text*, for Python 2 make sure you have decoded from `str` to `unicode`, for Python 3, from `bytes` to `str` *first*.

Emoji are complex beasts these days. The above will remove *complete, valid Emoji*. If you have 'incomplete' Emoji components such as [skin-tone codepoints](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-modifiers.html#component) (meant to be combined with *specific* Emoji only) then you'll have much more trouble removing those. The skin-tone codepoints are easy (just remove those 5 codepoints afterwards), but there is a [whole host of combinations](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-zwj-sequences.txt) that are made up of innocent characters such as ♀ U+2640 FEMALE SIGN or ♂ U+2642 MALE SIGN together with [variant selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)) and the [U+200D ZERO-WIDTH JOINER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) that have specific meaning in *other contexts too*, and you can't just regex those out, not unless you don't mind breaking text using Devanagari, or Kannada or CJK ideographs, to name just a few examples.

That said, the following Unicode 11.0 codepoints are *probably* safe to remove (based on filtering the [`Emoji_Component` Emoji-data designation](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji//11.0/emoji-data.txt)):

```
20E3          ;  (⃣)     combining enclosing keycap
FE0F          ; ()        VARIATION SELECTOR-16
1F1E6..1F1FF  ; (..)  regional indicator symbol letter a..regional indicator symbol letter z
1F3FB..1F3FF  ; (..)  light skin tone..dark skin tone
1F9B0..1F9B3  ; (..) red-haired..white-haired
E0020..E007F  ; (..)      tag space..cancel tag
```

which can be removed by creating a new regex to match those:

```
import re
try:
    uchr = unichr  # Python 2
    import sys
    if sys.maxunicode == 0xffff:
        # narrow build, define alternative unichr encoding to surrogate pairs
        # as unichr(sys.maxunicode + 1) fails.
        def uchr(codepoint):
            return (
                unichr(codepoint) if codepoint <= sys.maxunicode else
                unichr(codepoint - 0x010000 >> 10 | 0xD800) +
                unichr(codepoint & 0x3FF | 0xDC00)
            )
except NameError:
    uchr = chr  # Python 3

# Unicode 11.0 Emoji Component map (deemed safe to remove)
_removable_emoji_components = (
    (0x20E3, 0xFE0F),             # combining enclosing keycap, VARIATION SELECTOR-16
    range(0x1F1E6, 0x1F1FF + 1),  # regional indicator symbol letter a..regional indicator symbol letter z
    range(0x1F3FB, 0x1F3FF + 1),  # light skin tone..dark skin tone
    range(0x1F9B0, 0x1F9B3 + 1),  # red-haired..white-haired
    range(0xE0020, 0xE007F + 1),  # tag space..cancel tag
)
emoji_components = re.compile(u'({})'.format(u'|'.join([
    re.escape(uchr(c)) for r in _removable_emoji_components for c in r])),
    flags=re.UNICODE)
```

then update the above `remove_emoji()` function to use it:

```
def remove_emoji(text, remove_components=False):
    cleaned = emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(u'', text)
    if remove_components:
        cleaned = emoji_components.sub(u'', cleaned)
    return cleaned
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For Input `HMDA plot sales Agents`
It gives
`HMDA plot sales Agents `. Still not covering all the emoji's I guess.

Comment: @ascii_walker: that's an unpaired U+1F3FC EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-3 codepoint. Wether or not that's an emoji in itself is up for debate.

Comment: @ascii_walker: clearly, the emoji package doesn't see it as an emoji; if you paired it up with a supporting emoji, it would be removed. `` for example, is removed as that's a pairing of U+1F91F U+1F3FC, which is how the pattern is to be used.

Comment: Also for this input its not removing any of the emoji's(Not sure if they are emoji's)
Input: `PlotFlatHouseSaleAdvt`
Output: `PlotFlatHouseSaleAdvt`

Comment: @ascii_walker: I get `'PlotFlatHouseSaleAdvt'` for that. Are you sure you are using my implementation?

Comment: @ascii_walker: for the full skin-tone modifier list, see https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-modifiers.html; you'd have to separately create a regex for the [5 tone component codepoints](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-modifiers.html#component).

Comment: It gives `'PlotFlatHouseSaleAdvt'` after decoding the text as `remove_emoji1("PlotFlatHouseSaleAdvt".decode("utf-8")`

Comment: FYI: I am using python 2.7 and reading those text from a csv file

Comment: @ascii_walker: right, I was assuming Python 3 (Python 2.7 is very close to End Of Life, you should really consider upgrading!). The regex is aimed at Unicode text, handling Emoji in regexes as UTF-8 sequences opens up another huge can of worms. I'm not going to go there today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177803/discussion-between-ascii-walker-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn for your effort. Its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**The emoji.get_emoji_regexp() is outdated.**

If you want to remove emoji from strings, you can use emoji.replace_emoji() as shown in the examples below.

```
import emoji

def remove_emoji(string):
    return emoji.replace_emoji(string, '')
```

Visit https://carpedm20.github.io/emoji/docs/api.html#emoji.replace_emoji

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library instead of the `re` library you get access to Unicode properties then you can change your function to

```
def remove_emoji(self, string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("[\P{L}&&\P{D}&&\P{Z}&&\P{M}]", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', string)
```

Which will keep all letters, digits, separators  and marks (accents)

Comment: That's still *not enough*. You forgot `\P{P}` for starters. And `Sm` and `Sm` should be fine too; emoji are mostly `So` and `Sk` category symbols. Except for the ones that are not; the Emoji sequences in the `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI` mapping fall in to the categories Cf, Cn, Ll, Me, Mn, Nd, Pd, Po, Sk, Sm and So, so your patten would actually *leave some Emoji in place*.

Comment: Note that a lot of Emoji are formed from a combination of codepoints. For example, `'\U0001f477\U0001f3ff\u200d\u2640\ufe0f'` is *one* Emoji: ‍♀️. Your regex would leave the last codepoint in place, so `♀️`.  That can get confusing.

Comment: If I remember correctly the latest version of Unicode has an `emoji` property, but I don't know which code points it covers

Comment: Unicode 11 has [such Emoji-related properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties_and_Data_Files), but you risk leaving behind `Emoji_Component` codepoints still. *And* they are not formerly part of the UCD.

Comment: Also see [the full list of what codepoint has what Emoji property](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji//11.0/emoji-data.txt). Note however that the property is pretty useless. Digits have the property, as do `#` and `*`.