# Remove unicode encoded emojis from Twitter tweet

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, emoji, python-re

For a data science project I am tasked with the cleanup of our twitter data. The tweets contain unicode encoded emojis (and other stuff) in the form of `\ud83d\udcf8` (camera emoji) or `\ud83c\uddeb\ud83c\uddf7` (french flag) for example.

I am using the python-package "re" and so far I was successful in removing "simple" unicodes like `\u201c` (double quotation mark) with something like

```
text = re.sub(u'\u201c', '', text)
```

However, when I am trying to remove more complex structures, like for example

```
text = re.sub(u'\ud83d\udcf8', '', text) # remove camera emoji
text = re.sub(u'\ud83c\uddeb\ud83c\uddf7', '', text) # remove french flag emoji
```

nothing is happening, no matter if I prefix the string with an 'u', an 'r' or nothing at all. The unicode remains in the string.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Shawn Shroyer's answer i found out that

```
text = re.sub(u'\\ud83d\\udcf8', '', text)
```

works fine! I just had to escape the backslashes. Now only my second problem remains (*see below*).

**The second problem** is that I don't want to have to specify every single emoji individually, but instead I would like to remove them all in a much simpler fashion, but without removing ALL unicode characters, because I need to retain stuff like `\u2019` (single quotation mark).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing emojis from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @cullzie no, I already tried that one

Comment: [try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785357/11794224) that uses the emoji library

Comment: @Zeph this one does not work either, sorry

Comment: @EXQuIsIIt Please don't add answers to questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create an array of values you would like to replace and you need to escape the \ by adding another backslash, or adding 'ur' before your string so backslashes do not need to be escaped.

```
import re
to_remove_arr = [u"\ud83d\udcf8", u"\ud83c\uddeb\ud83c\uddf7"]
pattern_str = "|".join(to_remove_arr)    
text = re.sub(pattern_str, "", text)
```

Edit: the above solution will remove specific unicode characters - to remove all non-ASCII Unicode characters:

```
text = text.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
```

Edit: to remove only emojis I found:

```
def strip_emoji(text):
    RE_EMOJI = re.compile(u'([\U00002600-\U000027BF])|([\U0001f300-\U0001f64F])|([\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF])')
    return RE_EMOJI.sub(r'', text)
```

Comment: Edited answer to include re.sub  and combining the array of unicode characters into a single regex expression

Comment: thank you, this way I at least would have a working solution! But it would be tiresome to collect every single emoji individually, so hopefully someone has an idea to remove them all together ;)

Comment: Sorry - based on the question I thought you were looking to only remove specific unicode characters. Edited answer with a solution to remove all non-ascii characters

Comment: Saw your edit and included code to strip only emojis

Comment: That last one was the solution I was looking for, thanks! Some emojis are still slipping through, but I just have to adjust the ranges or add more. Thank you very much! :)