# Removing emoji from text remove also Japanese language

Tags: python, unicode, emoji

I use the follow code:

```
import re

def replace_emoji_space(string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                       u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                       u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                       u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                       u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                       u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                       u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                       "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r' ', string)
```

While string == '趣味でバルーンひねってます'
the results is just an empty string, why ?

This is what I get in pycharm:
[string in pyhon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YhtV.png)

Comment: I think it is because the string you are comparing isn't encoded as 'utf-8'

Comment: Are sure you decode your input to `utf16`?

Comment: I am working in python3 isn't every string is a unicode8 ?

Comment: I used this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python/33417311#comment54637275_33417311

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def replace_emoji_space(string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                       u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                       u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                       u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                       u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                       "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r' ', string)
```

The last 2 removed the japanese