# Translate to text a Emoji Unicode String un python

Tags: python, twitter, encode, emoji

I have a list of tweets that has been delivered as a csv.
But when I read them, the emojis unicode has been converted as str and I can't translate them to their real name ("waffle" or "heart").

```
def load_csv(csv_name):
    path = os.getcwd()
    df = pd.read_csv(path + "/" + csv_name, header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, sep=",", encoding="utf-8")
    return df

csv_name = "tweets_nikekaepernick.csv"
df = load_csv(csv_name)

text = df["tweet_full_text"].iloc[0]
text

Out[]: 'Hi <U+0001F602><U+0001F602><U+0001F480><U+0001F480><U+0001F480><U+0001F480>'
```

Comment: If I create a .csv with UTF emoticons like the ones you mention, and use `read_csv` to read it into a `DataFrame`, Python correctly prints the emoticons when accessing values from it. If you can provide a link to a data file that has this problem, that might shed some light on why you're seeing this behaviour. Also, can you mention the specific version of Python you're using?

Comment: Possibly the output device you're running the interpreter on doesn't support UTF-8 text output? How exactly are you running the above code?

Comment: Hi, i'm running this on Jupyter Notebook, with Python 3.8.8
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oldvYLOD1NpKSbrAKDwARe-LXpDiFIsi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: As an aside, `pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + "/" + "filename", ...)` is just a really inconvenient and clumsy way to say `pd.read_csv("filename", ...)`. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `demoji` . You can get more details about `demoji` at [here](https://pypi.org/project/demoji/).

**code**

```
import re
import demoji
demoji.download_codes()

text = 'Hi <U+0001F602><U+0001F602><U+0001F480><U+0001F480><U+0001F480><U+0001F480>'

# changed format with regex
text_ = re.sub('\+|>','',text).replace('<','\\').encode().decode('unicode-escape')

#find emoji
demoji.findall(text_)
```

**result**

```
demoji.findall(text_)
Out[1]: {'': 'skull', '': 'face with tears of joy'}
```

**More**

For more, if you wants to **remove** emojis, you can try the below code, which is referring form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python):

```
pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)

print(pattern.sub(r'', text_))
>>> Hi
```

Or, if you wants to translate your emoji to `str`, you can try:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.demojize(text_))

>>> Hi :face_with_tears_of_joy::face_with_tears_of_joy::skull::skull::skull::skull:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it still doesn't work :( 
Even if I paste the string as it appears, it won't find any emoji. Actually I never get to see the emoji image, I only get this <U+....> strings.
I tried 
` import demoji
demoji.download_codes()
text = 'Hi <U+0001F602><U+0001F602><U+0001F480><U+0001F480><U+0001F480><U+0001F480>'
demoji.findall(text) `
but I get
' {} '