# cleaning a string by removing emoticons

Tags: python, string, nlp, ascii

I'm using below code to do some cleaning of a string. However, it is not able to remove emoticons like "  ". Is there a way to do it?

```
import re
import string
s = '''Hi !こんにちは、私の給料は月額10000ドルです。 XO XO
私はあなたの料理が大好きです
私のフライトはAPX1999です。
私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
'''
# replace all ascii chars 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
replaced = re.sub(f'[{string.printable}]', '', s)
print(replaced)
```

Output :

```
こんにちは、私の給料は月額ドルです。私はあなたの料理が大好きです私のフライトはです。私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
```

Expected output :

```
こんにちは、私の給料は月額ドルです。私はあなたの料理が大好きです私のフライトはです。私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing emojis from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
import string
s = '''Hi !こんにちは、私の給料は月額10000ドルです。 XO XO
私はあなたの料理が大好きです
私のフライトはAPX1999です。
私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
'''
# replace all ascii chars 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
replaced = re.sub(f'[{string.printable}]', '', s)

emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                   "]", flags=re.UNICODE)

replaced = re.sub(emoji_pattern, '', replaced)

print(replaced)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import string
 
text =  '''Hi !こんにちは、私の給料は月額10000ドルです。 XO XO
私はあなたの料理が大好きです
私のフライトはAPX1999です。
私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。'''

pattern = re.compile(
    "(["
    "\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
    "\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
    "\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
    "\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
    "\U0001F700-\U0001F77F"  # alchemical symbols
    "\U0001F780-\U0001F7FF"  # Geometric Shapes Extended
    "\U0001F800-\U0001F8FF"  # Supplemental Arrows-C
    "\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF"  # Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
    "\U0001FA00-\U0001FA6F"  # Chess Symbols
    "\U0001FA70-\U0001FAFF"  # Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A
    "\U00002702-\U000027B0"  # Dingbats
    "])"
  )

text = re.sub(f'[{string.printable}]', '', text)
text = re.sub(pattern, r'', text)
```

```
こんにちは、私の給料は月額ドルです。私はあなたの料理が大好きです私のフライトはです。私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
```