# python web element to txt and use open file txt

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to convert the element from a web element to a string and send it to another function and use it in the file name. i tried many methods but failed. i am looking for ideas on how to do it. below my codes.

```
product_title = None

def product_title():
    global product_title
    product_title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#GoodsBlock > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.product-title > div > a")
    print(product_title.text)
    product_title.click()


def write_txt():
    file = open("games_files/"+product_title+".txt", "w")

product_title()
write_txt()
```

and error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\scrap_games.py", line 48, in <module>
    write_txt()
  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\scrap_games.py", line 41, in write_txt
    file = open("games_files/"+product_title.text+".txt", "w")
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i tried many methods but failed. i am looking for ideas on how to do it.

Comment: is the 'games_files' folder inside 'pythonProject'? If not then where is it?

Comment: yes inside. i have checked.

Comment: Does `print(product_title.text)` show the data/filename you need?

Comment: yes. when i print product title i see the text. but in function when i use there is no .text nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Selenium heavily, but this should fix the problem. Rather than using global and `+` strings, switching to a return and f-string helps move the info between def's. This is the main issue as your code is not setting the `product_title` variable.

Try:

```
def get_product_title():
    product_title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#GoodsBlock > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.product-title > div > a")    
    print(product_title.text)
    product_title.click()
    return product_title.text


def write_txt():
    file = open(f"games_files/{product_title}.txt", "w")

product_title = get_product_title()
write_txt()
```

I've changed the def name so it's clearer to help break down my answer. `product_title` gets the returned value of `product_title.text` from `get_product_title`, from your comment this contains the value you want. This saves having to worry about `global`ing inside your def.

`write_txt` now has an f-string which inserts the variable `product_title` without the need for `+`'s.

**EDIT: Emoji removal version**

Based on answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602709/22669764

EDIT #2: Wrapped the `product_title.text` in `str` and made it a variable in case the `product_title.click()` does anything to the value. Added `lstrip` and `rstrip` to hopefully mitigate the emoji's killing things.

Install emoji package with `pip install emoji`

```
import emoji

def get_product_title():
    product_title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#GoodsBlock > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.product-title > div > a")
    title = str(product_title.text)
    print(title)
    product_title.click()
    return title
    
def give_emoji_free_text(text):
    return str(emoji.replace_emoji(text, replace='')).lstrip().rstrip()

def write_txt():
    file = open(f"games_files/{clean_title}.txt", "w")

product_title = get_product_title()
clean_title = give_emoji_free_text(product_title)
write_txt()
```

Comment: unfortun doesnt work :(

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\scrap_games.py", line 42, in <module>
    product_title = product_title()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\scrap_games.py", line 24, in product_title
    return product_title.text
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Did you change the def name `get_product_title()` back to `product_title()`?

Comment: yes i changed it. text looks like this. can emojis affect the code not working?

✅ ❤️Awarded Platformer Bundle✅XBOX ONE|X|S KEY +VPN❤️

Comment: Yes, I imagine trying to parse a load of emoji's as a filename would likely break most filesystems. You would either need to strip them out or encode the string correctly if your filesystem allows emoji filenames. Just for fun I tried to create a file with that string, Windows was not happy about it in the slightest.

Comment: ohh is there a short way to clean these emojis in the text? and how can i send the variable into the function and create a clean file name? i have spent time with this code since morning :(

Comment: Try the emoji removal version I've added to my answer

Comment: hello again. unfortunately it gives me an error again. 

  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\scrap_games.py", line 49, in <module>
    product_title = get_product_title()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\scrap_games.py", line 26, in get_product_title
    return product_title.text
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\xbox\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 90, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: That looks to be an issue with the Selenium scraper, do you get text from `print(product_title.text)`?

Comment: yes print is working. error line is return product_title.text

Comment: Try updated code, I've made a couple of changes which might help. There really should be no issue, a return will only pass what is presented to it.

Comment: hi again. unfortun final codes dont work. your code deleted all emojis but now i have different problem when create txt file. emojis deleted but there are so many blank spaces. i have tried replace 
clean_title.replace(" ", "") like this but not working. 
here is output:
  file = open(f"games_files/{clean_title}.txt", "w")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'games_files/ Awarded Platformer BundleXBOX ONE|X|S KEY +VPN.txt'

Comment: Weirdness, I've just tried it and got `games_files/Awarded Platformer BundleXBOX ONE|X|S KEY +VPN.txt` placing a dummy title in the first def of `title = "✅ ❤️Awarded Platformer Bundle✅XBOX ONE|X|S KEY +VPN❤️"` just above the return. Are you using the version with `.lstrip().rstrip()` I edited it after updating so that that may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file = open("games_files/"+product_title.text+".txt", "w")
```

or

```
file = open("games_files/"+str(product_title)+".txt", "w")
```

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'games_files/<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
doesnt work :(

Comment: Try to replace punctuation characters with something, it seems you want not .text but whole element string to be name of file

Comment: there is text in the element. i just want to make that element into a string variable and make the file name this element. because i need to scan 2000 elements and create a txt file.